# Wordpress Permalink Issue

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

We recently decided to change our permalink structure from '/%postname%/' to '/%year%/%postname%/'.  For some reason, every time I change the permalink structure in the WP Admin all post just bounce to the main blog page but the URL is updated in the address bar to the new link structure.

Anyone have any idea why it would do this?  I dont get a 404 error it just simply never takes you into the post only to the main blog page.

```
Options+FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# BEGIN WordPress
'<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Make sure the .htaccess file gets updated as well.

Comment: Added my .htaccess file content above.  It looks to be correct, I think.